# Opscenter 4.0.2 and Cassandra 2.0.4 with SSL and Auth : agent can't connect

Tags: ssl, authentication, cassandra

I setup cassandra with inter-node SSL and client-to-server SSL and basic password auth.
No problem using cqlsh or python to connect to cassandra with any certificate as certificate_validation is disabled.

My opscenter cluster config is :

```
[jmx]
username =
password =
port = 7199

[kerberos_client_principals]

[kerberos]

[agents]
thrift_ssl_truststore = /usr/share/opscenter/conf/cassandra_client_trust.jks
thrift_ssl_truststore_password = changeme

[kerberos_hostnames]

[kerberos_services]

[cassandra]
username = cassandra
ssl_ca_certs = /usr/share/opscenter/conf/cassandra_external.pem
ssl_validate = False
seed_hosts = acacia
api_port = 9160
password = changeme
```

I'm trying to install the agent on the cassandra hosts using the tarball.
I set the address.yaml to :

```
stomp_interface: "10.235.10.7"
use_ssl: 1
```

Trying to start the agent (I had to add A LOT more memory to java than the default 40mb) :

```
 INFO [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,300 Connecting to Cassandra cluster: 10.235.10.104 (port 9160)
 INFO [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,316 Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
 INFO [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,322 Registering JMX me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_Agent Cluster:ServiceType=hector,MonitorType=hector
ERROR [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,556 MARK HOST AS DOWN TRIGGERED for host 10.235.10.104(10.235.10.104):9160
ERROR [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,557 Pool state on shutdown: :{10.235.10.104(10.235.10.104):9160}; IsActive?: true; Active: 1; Blocked: 1; Idle: 0; NumBeforeExhausted: 0
 INFO [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,557 Shutdown triggered on :{10.235.10.104(10.235.10.104):9160}
 INFO [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,557 Shutdown complete on :{10.235.10.104(10.235.10.104):9160}
 INFO [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,557 Host detected as down was added to retry queue: 10.235.10.104(10.235.10.104):9160
 WARN [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,558 Could not fullfill request on this host CassandraClient
 WARN [thrift-init] 2014-01-27 16:32:08,559 Exception:
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorTransportException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:33)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$2.execute(AbstractCluster.java:151)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$2.execute(AbstractCluster.java:145)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:104)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:258)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeClusterName(AbstractCluster.java:155)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:298)
        at clj_hector.core$cluster_name.invoke(core.clj:40)
        at opsagent.cassandra$setup_cassandra$f__352__auto____899$fn__919.invoke(cassandra.clj:360)
        at opsagent.cassandra$setup_cassandra$f__352__auto____899.invoke(cassandra.clj:358)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

I don't know if this is related to SSL or to user/password... but it's failing.
As the agent connect to the local Cassandra server, I expect it should know the login/pass of the cassandra user (or any superuser or maybe a regular user) ? doesn't he ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to a known race condition where the agent tries to connect to the local node via thrift before opscenterd is able to send SSL information.  The workaround is to manually configure the agent's SSL settings in address.yaml:

```
thrift_ssl_truststore: /etc/dse/conf/.truststore 
thrift_ssl_truststore_password: XYZ
```

and restart the agent.