# OpsCenter 5.0: No Data on Dashboard Graphs

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I have an OpsCenter 5.0 instance running and 10 agents connected.  The agents are in 2 regions in AWS, so everything is using external addresses to communication.  All the necessary ports are open, and in fact, the OpsCenter dashboard says "All agents connected".  I can also click on any of the nodes for details, and all the stats seem to be updating normally.

My only problem is that all the graphs show "No Data". The strange thing is that they seemed to be working for a few minutes after I first set it up, but then stopped recording any data.

I have restarted the server and all agent processes, but that didn't help.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions or ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!  Found a bunch of the following in the agent logs:

```
WARN [Thread-1] 2014-08-08 15:07:06,527 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [Thread-1] 2014-08-08 15:07:06,527 239710 operations dropped so far.
ERROR [thrift-processor-1] 2014-08-08 15:07:07,832 Error when proccessing thrift callme.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
```

This is kind of weird since all the other communication was fine, and the graphs initially worked.  To fix it, I just added the following to the address.yaml file on all the agents and restarted the agent service:

```
thrift_user: <username>
thrift_pass: <password>
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks! Where did you find about these directives? They're not documented here (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html); nor the need to configure the authentication details in the agent side

Comment: Found these settings on this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/581552/opscenter-4-1-ssl-agent-communication-vs-internal-authentication.  Not sure where they got them though since they're not in any of the docs.